# Get gradient of layer before activation with respect to input picture

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, gradient

Currently, I am working on a Universal Perturbation type of research, where I would use the gradient of the layer before the activation function to retrace the gradient step taken in the last iteration.
However, when I try to extract the gradient using K.gradients, I can't seem to extract the right stuff.

Either I get a tensor, which I don't want, or I get [zero]. What I want are the exact gradients of that second to last layer, given the input-image. This is what I currently have:

```
f_image = np.array(model.predict(image)).flatten()
I = (np.array(f_image)).flatten().argsort()[::-1]
I = I[0:num_classes]

pert_image = image
gradients = np.asarray(grads(pert_image,I))
```

Here grads should be the gradient function to get the exact gradients. When I use the following code, I get a tensor:

```
gradients = K.gradients(model.layers[-2].output, model.layers[0].input)[0]
```

Where the output is the I, which gives the largest influences before making the activation to classify, and the input is the perturbed image, starting off with the original image.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my `K.gradients` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K.gradients computes the gradient in a *symbolic* way, you need to evaluate the gradient with actual inputs in order to get *numerical* values. You can do this using `K.function` to build a callable:

```
import keras.backend as K

gradients = K.gradients(model.layers[-2].output, model.layers[0].input)[0]
grad_fn = K.function([model.input], [gradients])
```

Then you can now call `grad_fn` with an appropriate input (including the batch dimension) that will return the numerical values of the gradient:

```
actual_gradients = grad_fn([image])
```